# Calling a macro from another macro's if condition

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a very simple macro to determine if a macro parameter was supplied or not. However, I am obtaining an error with the message "required operator not found in expression: %is_def(&param1)." What is wrong with this code?

```
%macro is_def(var);
    (%length(&var) > 0);
%mend;

%macro do_something(param1);

    %if %is_def(&param1) %then %do;
        %put parameter was provided;
    %end;
    %else %do;
        %put parameter was NOT supplied;
    %end;

%mend;

%do_something(5);
```

Comment: Why not just use `%length(&param1)` instead of using your sub macro?  If the length is 0 then it is false otherwise it is true.

Answer (score 3):

You macro %is_def is a function style macro.  You have an extra semicolon in it which is causing the error.

As written, you call `%is_def(hello)` the macro will return this code:

```
(5 > 0);
```

The 5 is because hello is 5 characters long.  Note the semicolon at the end, you don't want that semicolon.

As written, the %IF statement in %Do_Something will end up like:

```
%if (5 > 0); %then %do;
```

And looking at that, you can see why the semicolon causes the problem.

To fix, you should remove the semicolon, i.e. change to:

```
%macro is_def(var);
    (%length(&var) > 0)
%mend;
```

Another possible enhancement would be to have the is_def macro return simply a 1 or 0 for true or false, rather than return `(5 > 0)`.  For that, you could do:

```
%macro is_def(var);
    %eval(%length(&var) > 0)
%mend;
```

There is an EXCELLENT paper on this subject (testing for blank parameters), which considers this method as well as several others, and ends with a utility macro `%IsBlank`.  Suggest you check it out:  http://changchung.com/download/022-2009.pdf.

Comment: Great answer and very interesting referenced paper.